# Youtube Live streaming using ffmpeg container webm

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to stream youtube live using webm container vp8 codec but enable to done using code or command.

```
     ffmpeg -i E:/Video/Waka.mp4 -g 48 -f webm -vcodec libvpx-vp9  rtmp://youtube live url
```

its work fine with flv

Comment: RTMP is an Adobe protocol so I don't think WebM muxer can work. Also, doesn't look like YT accepts VP8/9 - see https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?hl=en&ref_topic=6136989

Comment: Is it possible for udp streaming with webm muxer?